# Several questions regarding sklearn.metrics.roc_curve() - Thresholds, Luck-Label, Equal Error Rate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, roc, threshold

I have some questions regarding ROC graphs.
I use the sklearn.metrics.roc_curve() function to get my tpr, fpr and the thresholds.
My first question is, whether the thresholds are arbitrarily chosen?
Would I get a different ROC graph every time I use the exact same code?

2nd question is about a "luck" label that I see very often plotted in ROC graphs.
It seems to be a straight line from the left bottom to the upper right corner.
Why is it called "luck"? It seems to be a graph, that indicates points where tpr = fpr.
But I can't explain myself why it is called luck.

My last question is about equal error rate. I encountered on Github someone who calculated the equal error rate and plotted in also in the ROC graph. My question is, what this information gives us exactly? The code was as follows:

```
    ...
    eer = brentq(lambda x: 1. - x - interp1d(fpr, tpr)(x), 0., 1.) ...
    ...
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=lw, label='(AUC = %0.2f, EER = %0.2f)' % (roc_auc, eer)) 
    ...
    plt.plot([eer], [1-eer], marker='o', markersize=5, color="navy")
    ...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to this site MaxM! Please only ask one question at a time. Check the help center to learn how to ask a good question and be more likely to receive an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also your questions already have been answered on this site, so make sure to do a quick search before asking.

Comment: Hello Calimo, I searched for an answer for my questions. But I couldn't find a proper answer.